# Running daml script on `daml start`

Tags: daml

I have a daml file with just one script

```
module User where
import Daml.Script
makeAdmin =
  script do
    admin <- allocateParty "Admin"
    submit admin do
      createCmd User with username = admin
template User with
    username: Party
  where
    signatory username

    key username: Party
    maintainer key
...
```

Is there a way to execute the script any time I run `daml start`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! This is explained in [the documentation for Daml Script](https://docs.daml.com/daml-script/index.html#using-daml-script-for-ledger-initialization), specifically:

> You can use Daml script to initialize a ledger on startup. To do so, specify an `init-script: ScriptExample:initializeFixed` field in your `daml.yaml`. This will automatically be picked up by `daml start` and used to initialize sandbox.

In your case, that would be:

```yaml
init-script: User:makeAdmin
```